# Spark client memory configuration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run multiple spark clients on Airflow(ETL scheduler).

I'm running in cluster mode on YARN, therefore ApplicationMaster Executor and Driver are all running on executor in Yarn context.
However, my spark client which sample the process and monitor the state is running in airflow worker.

The problem is that the Spark client take lot's of memory ~500 MB per job. It may sound as not much in terms of executors or drivers but for the role of spark client it sounds crazy.

My question is, how can I configure/manipulate spark client memory/cpu requirements can I limit it's intervals ? can I limit it's memory with flags?

Comment: You can run your Spark Context on the cluster side with `--deploy-mode cluster`. Have you considered this solution yet ?

Comment: I'm already running in cluster mode. But when you do that the Spark client (not driver) running in the machine which you are submitting from.
It's the process that printing
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
This process consume 500MB for no apparent reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in spark code it make a distinction if it's running in standalone mode or cluster mode. For standalone it set a default of `-Xmx 1G` and in cluster mode it doesn't have default but it trying to read java options from environment variable called `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS`.

So if you wanna set any java opts for the **client java process only** use `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTS`